# Email Verification for Web App Registration

Tags: email, user-interface, registration, user-experience, verification

Im working on a SAAS web app/website and trying to figure out the best way to make the sign up/registration as easy as possible for the user.

So far, we've got it down to only a few fields for the user to fill in, as soon as they hit "sign up" I thought it would look nice to display a loading animation with "creating your account" and fade right in to the interface.

I've noticed that a bunch of successful web applications are currently allowing registration and sending the user directly into the application without requiring an email registration for access.

I just really need some clarification - is the email verification thing only around so the company cannot be accused of spamming users? (i.e. when they send out routine emails)

Is there any way around this? Obviously to use the app correctly, they would need to receive the routine emails. What are your thoughts on this?

Thanks Everyone

Comment: StackOverflow is more of a programming/coding site; your question should probably be [asking about specific programming problems you are running into](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Your question might better be answered on either the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) or [Web Masters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) sites.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the case was solved, but we did exactly the same solution at mailcheck.co when you try signing up, invalid emails won't be accessed.